# How to keep two wordpress blogs under the same site?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, blogs

I am working on a blog in the media front. I want to create two blogs under the same wordpress site in such a way that the session and the user base is common for the both and i even want to have the same url for both that is

```
www.example.com
```

for both. So is there a possibility to do that and as of now i have created two separate blogs under the same database but the issue is the session is separate for both and even the user base and even the url changes. So can someone help out with this. All i need is a little guidance and i can build upon it.

thanks

Comment: Your question is a bit confusion. Can you elaborate in detail. Well, I have understood that you want to use the same database for user management but under the same directory is not clear

Comment: `"the session and the user base is common for the both"` , `"the session is separate for both"` so which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want two WordPress blog and one database for the user. You need to add following code into your both wp_config.php

```
define(CUSTOM_USER_TABLE,'wp_users');
define(CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE,'wp_usermeta');
```

Also you need to Replace the wp_ with the prefix to what you want. You may see https://wordpress.org/support/topic/two-blogs-working-from-one-user-database for more help.